# Use one property from an Interface in another Interface with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How can I use one property from an interface in another interface in TypeScript?

`One` is provided by a library and `Two` is my code:

```
interface One {
  foo: string;
  position: 'right' | 'left';
};

interface Two {
  bar: string;
  position: 'right' | 'left';
};
```

The above works but I was hoping I could do something like:

```
interface Two {
  bar: string;
  position: One['position']
};
```

Comment: This should work, literally exactly as you have written it. What is the issue specifically that you are seeing with your bottom snippet?

Comment: Did you try it? You CAN do that

Comment: Sorry it just my linter complaining saying "TS2314: Generic type 'BubbleProps ' requires 1 type argument(s)." Which was fixed by BubbleProps<any>['position']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really get your question because you already answered it. The following is correct and works as you expect:

```js
interface One {
  foo: string;
  position: "right" | "left";
};

interface Two {
  bar: string;
  position: One["position"]  // "right" | "left"
};
```

See the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIhQbwFDOTAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG5dkAHAs4MYAkUgIiuoAsw3ZAB9k3ADYQYQ+gF962UJFiIUAFQDuBZDjwAjOFFIUqIOg2at2nUuggBtblbYcQ3ALrYF2bEA).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to `extend` `One` on `Two`

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIhQbwFDOTAewIC5kBnMKUAcwG5dkAHAs4MYAkUgciuoAsw3ZAB9k3ADYQYQ%20gF962UJFiIUAFQDuBZBAAekEABMyaDMhx4ARnCikKVEHWwLs2BJwrkCAWwhh%20GlItHQBeCwY8QhJxaO4AGkjkGztxFISk5lZ2Th4%20QW4XWiA)

```
interface One {
  foo: string;
  position: 'right' | 'left';
};

interface Two extends One {
  bar: string;
};

const something: Two = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    position: 'right'
};
```

Obviously this means that the property `foo` would then be present on your `Two` interface, but it's not clear if that is an issue or not.